# $http.get method in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function and several $http get requests inside it. I need to call another function after it executes every $http request. But it always executes the function before request been completed. what is the reason? Is there a way to solve it?

```
$scope.json=function(){
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.get(DataElementUrl).then(function (response) {
            if (!response.data == "")
            dataElementJson = response.data;

        });
        $http.get(categoryComboUrl).then(function (response) {
                if (!response.data == "")
                    categoryComboJson = response.data;                   
        });
        $http.get(categoryUrl).then(function (response) {
                    if (!response.data == "")
                       categoryJson = response.data;                        
        });
        check++;
        $scope.getJson();
};
```

Comment: Move it inside the "then" section.

Comment: you could use a promise: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770325/AngularJS-Promises-The-Definitive-Guide

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use $q's function 'all':

```
    var a = $http.get(DataElementUrl).then(function (response) {
        if (!response.data == "")
        dataElementJson = response.data;

    });
    var b = $http.get(categoryComboUrl).then(function (response) {
            if (!response.data == "")
                categoryComboJson = response.data;                   
    });
    var c = $http.get(categoryUrl).then(function (response) {
                if (!response.data == "")
                   categoryJson = response.data;                        
    });

    $q.all([a, b,c]).then(function(result) {
      check++;
      $scope.getJson();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because network calls in javascript are asynchronous. What you should do it look into the [q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service that angular offers. It is a promise library.

If you want to call a method when all 3 to finish, what you'll need to use is

```
.all([promise1, promise2], fulfilled, rejected)
```

which will call the fulfilled callback when all promises in the array are fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

I would use $q.all() like this:

```
$scope.json=function(){
    $scope.loading = true;

    var promises = [$http.get(DataElementUrl),
                    $http.get(categoryComboUrl),
                    $http.get(categoryUrl)]

    $q.all(promises).then(function(results){
          dataElementJson = results[0].data,
          categoryComboJson = results[1].data,
          categoryJson = results[2].data
    });
};
```